# Persists One RLMObject

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my app I have a CustomUser which inherits from RLMObject.

I am wondering how do I store 1 object only for this CustomUser object?

```
func saveUser() {
     let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

     realm.beginWriteTransaction()
     realm.addObject(customUser)
     realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```

This code will write an additional object to the database everytime it runs. Resulting in many objects in database after the code is run multiple times.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to query Realm to check if there are any previously saved objects before going ahead and adding a new one.

```
func saveUser() {
     let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

     if CustomUser.allObjects().count > 0 {
          return   
     }

     realm.beginWriteTransaction()
     realm.addObject(customUser)
     realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```

On a more advanced note, if you want to reference your single `CustomUser` object explicitly, you can use Realm's primary key feature to directly query for that specific object. There's more information on [Realm's website](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) on how to set up classes to use primary keys (In the Objective-C section, since it looks like you're using the Objective-C bridged version).

Good luck!